# Setting up Proxy with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, user-agent

I have a question and my classmate can't fix it either:

how to set up a proxy using requests module?

I think it is easy and I can fix it very quickly. I can use :

```
proxy = {
            'http':'http://74.125.204.103' #just an example
        }
```

and

```
requests.get(www.youtube.com,proxies = proxy)
```

And we thought it will connect with 74.125.204.103

But ***WE ARE WRONG***!
It still connects with my own IP address. We use youtube and connect on on video but the times watched is not changing. we also use grabify and IT's still the same.**So how can I set up the proxy in other ways?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're getting this because you only have the proxy specified for HTTP and youtube will redirect you to HTTPS at which point requests has no proxy information.

```py
proxies = {
  'http':'http://proxy:port',
  'https':'http://proxy:port'
}
```

Try adding the line for the https schema.